# Creating a folder and set as working directory for saving stdout files and images

Tags: python, directory, stdout, working-directory

In my code, I create a textfile for the stdout and also save several .png images and .mat matrices - when the code finishes running there are a lot of files inside the directory

I want the code to be able to create a new directory inside the folder where my code is running, and save the .txt file as well as the output .png and .mat to this newly created folder.

I have figured out that to create the new directory I should do:

```
import os
os.mkdir('folder')
```

And to create the output file and set the stdout there it is

```
import sys
filename = open('filename.txt','w')
sys.stdout = filename
```

I tried using open('folder/filename.txt','w') but i get the error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Thank you!

Comment: works perfectly for me

Comment: Chances are you need an absolute path.  Python will resolve a relative path relative to your current working directory (the directory you were in when you ran the script--not the directory the script itself is in).

Comment: the file filename.txt is created inside the newly created folder?

Comment: To "set as working directory", just use [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Comment: Also, if you want to debug what Python thinks a relative pathname means, just do, e.g., `print(os.path.abspath('filename.txt'))`. (And even if you want other people to debug the problem for you, do that, for both paths, with your actual code, and post the results as part of the question.)

Comment: That looks right to me.  I'd probably set my foldername as a variable to guard against typos: foldername = 'folder'; os.mkdir(foldername); filename = os.path.join(foldername, 'filename.txt'; output_file = open(filename, 'w')

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper thanks, using the os.path.join is what solved the problem.

Comment: @abarnert thanks i have done that myself and realised that i needed to join the path to the current working directory.

Comment: You used a backslash in the path and didn't escape it didn't you?

Comment: @IonutHulub: Great guess. (And to the OP, if he's right: This is exactly why you have to post _exactly_ the same code you tried, not just something kind of similar. If you said "I tried using `open('folder\filename.txt','w')`", someone would have found your problem immediately, instead of an hour and a half-dozen questions later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to create the file 'filename.txt' inside the folder you just made ('folder')?

Given that's the case, use os.path.join()

```
import sys
filename = open(os.path.join('folder','filename.txt'),'w')
sys.stdout = filename
```

Now sys.stdout points to the file which is inside the new folder